# TikZ: how to set text position over a row

Tags: tikz-styles

I would like to put text ("yes" or "no") over a flowchart arrow. But with this code:

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2cm (all sides)
i]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!50]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
%\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
 \coordinate (cone) at (0,0);
\begin{scope} [name=scope1]%[thin]%--------------------inizio primo blocco (scope)-----------
\node (start) [startstop,align=left] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};
\node (pro2a) [process, left of=dec1, xshift=-2cm] {Process 2a text text text text text text text text text text};
\node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=2cm] {Process 2b};
\node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};

    %------------------------inizio linee di collegamento
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
%\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=east] {yes} (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[anchor=west] {no} (pro2b);
%\draw [arrow] (dec1) |- node[anchor=south] {no} (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
```

the text are not over the arrow, but in the middle and at the extreme right, or left. Why is this?

P.S.: Ok, it runs! But if I would like to connect "out1" node with the "in1" node, without overlapping the line with any other node, what do I to do?

Comment: try with `node[anchor=east, above] {yes}` and `node[anchor=west,above] {no}`. And welcome to TeX.SX.

Comment: @RenatoP please see if my edit corresponds to the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to change the options of the nodes to:

```
\node[pos=<..>,above]
```

The `pos` value is included between 0 and 1, where 0 corresponds to the beginning of the arrow and 1 to the end of it. The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2cm (all sides)
i]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!50]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]

\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
%\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
 \coordinate (cone) at (0,0);
\begin{scope} [name=scope1]%[thin]%--------------------inizio primo blocco (scope)-----------
\node (start) [startstop,align=left] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below of=start] {Input};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Process 1};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro1, yshift=-0.5cm] {Decision 1};
\node (pro2a) [process, left of=dec1, xshift=-2cm] {Process 2a text text text text text text text text text text};
\node (pro2b) [process, right of=dec1, xshift=2cm] {Process 2b};
\node (out1) [io, below of=pro2a] {Output};
\node (stop) [startstop, below of=out1] {Stop};

    %------------------------inizio linee di collegamento
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[pos=0.5,above] {yes} (pro2a);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node[pos=0.5,above] {no} (pro2b);
\draw [arrow] (pro2b) |- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro2a) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

Is this what you want?
[image]

To produce the arrow that goes back to "input" you only need this code:

```
\draw [arrow] (out1.west) --++ (-1,0) |- (in1);
```

Answer (score 0):

- in question as well in the [MarcoG answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261718/tikz-how-to-set-text-position-over-a-row/261719#261719) is used obsolete syntax `\tikzstyle`. now is recommended to use `tikzset`
- positioning of flowchart block is simpler if you use the `positioning` library
- use of the `chains` library and its macro `join` make code simpler and shorter
- the library `quotes` enables simple adding labels to desired paths

  ```
  \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                  chains,
                  quotes,
                  positioning,
                  shapes.geometric}

  \makeatletter
  \tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}% for discontinue join macro
  \makeatother
  %
  \tikzset{FlowChart/.style = {% can be used in any flowchart
         arr/.style = {semithick, -Stealth},
        base/.style = {draw, text width=32mm, minimum height=8mm, align=center},
   startstop/.style = {base, rectangle, rounded corners, fill=red!30},
     process/.style = {base, rectangle, fill=orange!30},
          io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                       trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110,
                       fill=blue!30},
    decision/.style = {base, diamond, aspect=1.5, fill=green!30,
                       inner sep=0pt},
     every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right}
                              }
          }
   \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[FlowChart,
      % adopting FlowChart to this diagram
           node distance = 6mm and 12mm,
             start chain = A going below,
      base/.append style = {on chain=A, join=by arr}
                          ]
  \node   [startstop]     {Start};        % A-1
  \node   [io]            {Input};
  \node   [process]       {Process 1};
  \node   [decision]      {Decision 1};   % A-4
  \node   [process, left=of A-4] {Process 2a text text text text text text text text text text};
  \node   [io]            {Output};
  \node   [startstop]     {Stop};         % A-7
  %
  \node   [process, suppress join,
           right=of A-4] {Process 2b};    % A-8
  % lines not included in join macro
  \path       (A-4) to ["yes" ]   (A-5);
  \draw[arr]  (A-4) to ["no" ']   (A-8);
  \draw[arr]  (A-8) |- (A-3);
      \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]