# How to set column width and column height while creating flowchart in tikz

Tags: color, tikz-styles, multicolumn, backgrounds, flow-charts

This is a followup to my previous post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546281/setting-background-color-in-flowchart/546626?noredirect=1#comment1381050_546626).

I've a flowchart created in the following manner.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   % changed
\usepackage{tikz}               % added
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}


\begin{document} 

 \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 4mm and 10mm,
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm, align=center}, 
   steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                   minimum height=1cm, text width=24mm},    % changed
 process/.style = {base,
                   minimum height=3cm, text width=34mm,     % changed 
                   fill=white},
 decision/.style  = {diamond, minimum height=1cm ,
                    draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2mm},
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, draw=none, fit=#1, fill=#2} % added
                  ]
\node (process1) [process]                      {text text};
\node (process2) [decision, right=of process1]   {text text
    text };
\node (process3) [process, right=of process2]   {text text text};
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}, below =of process1]{process4}{fig.png};
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}, below =of process2]{process5}{fig.png};
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}, below =of process3]{process6}{fig.png};

\node (step1) [steps, above=of process1]   {Step 1};
\node (step2) [steps, above=of process2]   {Step 2};
\node (step3) [steps, above=of process3]   {Step 3};
%
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\node[FIT=(step1) (process1) (process4)/red!20] {};
\node[FIT=(step2) (process2) (process5)/red!40] {};
\node[FIT=(step3) (process3) (process6)/red!60] {};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

The column heights are uneven and the nodes in each row is not evenly aligned. I'd couldn't find an option to set maximum height to styles. Suggestions on how to set uniform column heights, uniform column widths and how to position the nodes in each row evenly will be really helpful.

Based on the code provided in the final update posted in the solution provded below, I tried

```
 \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm, align=center}, 
   steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                   minimum height=1cm, text width=24mm},    % changed
 process/.style = {base,
                   minimum height=3cm, text width=34mm,     % changed 
                   fill=white},
 decision/.style  = {diamond, minimum height=1cm ,
                    draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2mm},
 img/.style={inner sep=0pt,execute at begin node={%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{#1}}},%added
  >=Stealth 
                  ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1em,row sep=1em,nodes in empty cells,
row 1/.style={nodes=steps,execute at begin node={Step \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}},
row 4/.style={nodes={text width=9em,align=center}}]
(mat) {
 & &  \\
 |[process]| text text & 
 |[process]| text text text text text text text text &
 |[process]| text text \\ 
 |[img=example-image-a]| & |[img=example-image-b]| &
 |[img=example-image-c]|\\[-1em]
 text & text & text \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
{\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {red!20,red!40,red!60} {
 \node[fit=(mat-1-\Y) (mat-2-\Y) (mat-3-\Y) (mat-4-\Y),fill=\X]{};
}
}
\path[-Stealth] (mat-2-1) % 2nd row, 1st column
 edge (mat-2-2) % 2nd row, 2nd column
 (mat-2-3) edge  (mat-2-2)
  (mat-2-2) edge (mat-3-2);  % 3rd row, 2nd column
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Output:

[image]

I am not sure why node in second row second column has shifted down when the text is long. This disorients the arrows too.

Comment: You only need to add `nodes={anchor=center}` to the options of the matrix. I added this key to the codes in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `current bounding box` node to make the heights of these even. (You forgot to add the definition of `\ImageNode` so I made something up.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   % changed
\usepackage{tikz}               % added
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}


\begin{document} 

 \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 4mm and 10mm,
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm, align=center}, 
   steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                   minimum height=1cm, text width=24mm},    % changed
 process/.style = {base,
                   minimum height=3cm, text width=34mm,     % changed 
                   fill=white},
 decision/.style  = {diamond, minimum height=1cm ,
                    draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2mm},
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{base, draw=none, fit=#1, fill=#2} % added
                  ]
\newcommand\ImageNode[3][]{%
\node[#1](#2) {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{#3}};
}
\node (process1) [process]                      {text text};
\node (process2) [decision, right=of process1]   {text text
    text };
\node (process3) [process, right=of process2]   {text text text};
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}, below =of process1]{process4}{example-image-a};
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}, below =of process2]{process5}{example-image-b};
\ImageNode[label={-90:text}, below =of process3]{process6}{example-image-c};

\node (step1) [steps, above=of process1]   {Step 1};
\node (step2) [steps, above=of process2]   {Step 2};
\node (step3) [steps, above=of process3]   {Step 3};
%
\path (current bounding box.north) coordinate (N)
 (current bounding box.south) coordinate (S);
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\node[FIT=(N-|process1) (S-|process1) (step1) (process1) (process4)/red!20] {};
\node[FIT=(N-|process2) (S-|process2) (step2) (process2) (process5)/red!40] {};
\node[FIT=(N-|process3) (S-|process3) (step3) (process3) (process6)/red!60] {};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I think your starting point is unnecessarily complicated. There are much easier and more robust possibilities to do this. You could use a `matrix` and things will be nicely positioned.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning,
                matrix,
                shapes.geometric}


\begin{document} 

 \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm, align=center}, 
   steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                   minimum height=1cm, text width=24mm},    % changed
 process/.style = {base,
                   minimum height=3cm, text width=34mm,     % changed 
                   fill=white},
 decision/.style  = {diamond, minimum height=1cm ,
                    draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2mm},
 img/.style={execute at begin node={%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{#1}}},%added
                  ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1cm,row sep=1em,nodes in empty cells,nodes={anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes=steps,execute at begin node={Step \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}}]
(mat) {
 & &  \\
 |[process]| text text & 
 |[decision]| text text text &
 |[process]| text text \\ 
 |[img=example-image-a]| & |[img=example-image-b]| &
 |[img=example-image-c]|\\[-1em]
 text & text & text \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
{\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {red!20,red!40,red!60} {
 \node[fit=(mat-1-\Y) (mat-2-\Y) (mat-3-\Y) (mat-4-\Y),fill=\X]{};
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then it is very easy to make the column widths even, too.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning,
                matrix,
                shapes.geometric}


\begin{document} 

 \begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    base/.style = {rectangle, draw, inner sep=2mm, align=center}, 
   steps/.style = {base, rounded corners, fill=gray!50, 
                   minimum height=1cm, text width=24mm},    % changed
 process/.style = {base,
                   minimum height=3cm, text width=34mm,     % changed 
                   fill=white},
 decision/.style  = {diamond, minimum height=1cm ,
                    draw=black, fill=white, inner sep=2mm},
 img/.style={inner sep=0pt,execute at begin node={%
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{#1}}},%added
  >=Stealth 
                  ]
\matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=1em,row sep=1em,nodes in empty cells,nodes={anchor=center},
row 1/.style={nodes=steps,execute at begin node={Step \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}},
row 4/.style={nodes={text width=9em,align=center}}]
(mat) {
 & &  \\
 |[process]| text text & 
 |[decision]| text text text &
 |[process]| text text \\ 
 |[img=example-image-a]| & |[img=example-image-b]| &
 |[img=example-image-c]|\\[-1em]
 text & text & text \\
};
\scoped[on background layer]
{\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {red!20,red!40,red!60} {
 \node[fit=(mat-1-\Y) (mat-2-\Y) (mat-3-\Y) (mat-4-\Y),fill=\X]{};
}
}
\path[-Stealth] (mat-2-1) % 2nd row, 1st column
 edge (mat-2-2) % 2nd row, 2nd column
 (mat-2-3) edge  (mat-2-2)
  (mat-2-2) edge (mat-3-2);  % 3rd row, 2nd column
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How does that work?

- The matrix has the name `mat`, so the nodes in the matrix have the names `mat-<i>-<j>`, where `<i>` is the row and `<j>` the column.
- Hence `(mat-2-3) edge  (mat-2-2)` connects the node in the third column of the second row with the node in the second column of the same row.
- `row 1/.style-{...}` is described on p. 325 of pgfmanual v3.1.5. Here the style

  row 1/.style={nodes=steps,execute at begin node={Step \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}},

is special in that it makes use of the count `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` to make the nodes of this row use the style `steps`, and to fill it with the `row` index. So you do not have to do anything more to get the boxes `1`, `2`, `3`, and if you add a column, a fourth node will appear automatically.

Comment: learnt something new -- the base definition -- and the steps and  process configured on the base -- so the decision style can be configured on the base style as a rotated rectangle -- just a thought

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat Thanks a lot for the solution posted. I really like the matrix option, I'd to know if it is possible to add arrows between nodes while using matrix method

Comment: @Natasha Absolutely. Arrows from where to where? (I'll look at it in a bit.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you. Between any two consecutive nodes(row-wise and column-wise) e.g. from  process1 to  process2 or process1 to process4(image-A). While using `\node`, I use `\draw [arrow] (process1) -- (process4);` or `\draw [arrow] (process4) -- (process5);` . Side note: procees1 to 6 dfined in the original post.

Comment: Also , could you please explain how row 1/.style and row 4/.style works in the solution posted above?

Comment: @Natasha I added these to the update in the last example.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you very much. Could you please have a look at my edit?